# `textNode.splitText(pos)` messes up caret position in Safari, moves it BEFORE the new node. Bug?

Tags: javascript, text, safari, nodes, caret

When splitting text nodes (while typing) using `.splitText()` in Safari, the caret gets moved before the newly created node - in Chrome and Firefox it maintains its position at the end of the line, as expected.

I'm wondering, have I came across a bug, what would be a clean workaround?

```js
function wrapWorld({target}) {
  const node = target.childNodes[0];
  const pos = node.nodeValue.indexOf('world');
  console.log(pos);
  
  if (pos > 0) {
    //watch the caret in Safari jump before "world" when split :(
    const newNode = node.splitText(pos);
  }
}
```

```css
#editor {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p>Type "hello world" in Safari, watch the caret jump before "world" when it gets split</p>

<div id="editor" 
     contenteditable="true"
     oninput="wrapWorld(event)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell for sure if this is actually a bug or not, I didn't make extensive search in the specs to know what should happen here (content-editable is generally under-specced...), but both behaviors sounds quite logical to me, like I would expect the cursor to go back if the content was just removed.

Now, you can actually force Chrome and Firefox's behavior, which is probably a good idea anyway.

To do so, use the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) to know where your cursor currently is, then after you did your splitting, set it to the new position, that you can calculate using your splitting index.

```js
function wrapWorld( { target } ) {
  const sel = getSelection(); // get current selection
  const range = sel.getRangeAt( 0 ); // extract active Range
  const node = range.endContainer; // we should be collapsed, so startContainer === endContainer
  const cursor_pos = range.endOffset; // the position of our cursor in the whole node
  const txt_pos = node.nodeValue.indexOf( 'world' );

  if ( txt_pos > -1 ) {
    const new_node = node.splitText( txt_pos );
    const new_pos = cursor_pos - txt_pos;
    if( new_pos > -1 ) {
      range.setStart( new_node, new_pos ); // update our range
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange( range ); // update the Selection
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#editor {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p>Type "hello world" in Safari, watch the caret stay where it belongs</p>

<div id="editor" 
     contenteditable="true"
     oninput="wrapWorld(event)">
</div>
```